# Using dyn trait with a hierarchy of marker traits

Tags: rust, traits

I'm using the open source rust pcap library (https://github.com/rust-pcap/pcap) whose main Capture struct uses a system of [market traits to denote](https://github.com/rust-pcap/pcap/blob/main/src/lib.rs#L766) which functions are available during which lifecycle state/phase of the capture (e.g., you can't 'sendpacket' on a Capture in the "DEAD" state).  It has a hierarchy of State traits such that, e.g.,  "Activated" is a trait that is implemented by both the "Active", "Dead" and "Offline" states:

```
pub trait Activated: State {}
impl Activated for Active {}
impl Activated for Offline {}
impl Activated for Dead {}
pub trait State {}
impl State for Inactive {}
impl State for Active {}
impl State for Offline {}
impl State for Dead {}

pub struct Capture<T: State + ?Sized> {
...
}
```

With that code, I am trying unsuccessfully to convert from a parameterized+bounded trait as a <T: Activated + ?Sized> to a Capture, e.g., :

```
fn foo<T: Activated + ?Sized>(&mut capture: Capture<T>) {
    bar(capture as Capture<dyn Activated>);
}

fn bar(&mut capture: Capture<dyn Activated>) {
 ...
}
```

... but am getting an error:

> non-primitive cast: `&mut pcap::Capture<T>` as `&mut pcap::Capture<dyn pcap::Activated>` `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object

... which I don't understand at all, despite a fair bit of reading on this.  Can someone please explain to me how to do this (or why it's wrong to think this should work)?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should copy & paste your [mre] because what you have here doesn't compile for various reasons none of which related to the cast. I can't get the compiler to output your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current Rust, you can *only* coerce from `Foo<T>` to `Foo<dyn Trait>` if `T` is a sized type. This is because the conversion requires attaching a vtable pointer for `Trait`, and said vtable is only available when `T` is a regular, non-`dyn` type. So, this code,

```rust
fn foo<T: Activated + ?Sized>(&mut capture: Capture<T>) {
    bar(capture as Capture<dyn Activated>);
}
```

will always fail to compile because `T: ?Sized`, meaning that `T` might be already a `dyn`, and you can't cast from a `dyn` to an arbitrary different `dyn`.

There is an unstable feature, [`trait_upcasting`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/trait-upcasting.html) ([#65991](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65991)) that will enable dyn conversions to supertraits, like `Capture<dyn Activated>` to `Capture<dyn State>`, but that still does not include conversion from an arbitrary `T: ?Sized`. (In fact, if `T = [Foo]`, a type that is dynamically sized for a different reason, then it's impossible for an entirely different reason than traits — the compiler does not support a type being simultaneously vtable-based (having a pointer) and a slice (having a length). That restriction could in principle be lifted, but it'd be more new territory.)

To recap: You will need to organize your program so that you do not need to convert a `?Sized` type to a trait object, because that is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  If I can impinge on your patience further, so should this work if I dropped the question mark from foo<T: Activated + Sized> to force it to be sized?  This is an API from the library, so I can't actually make that change, but just so I know.

Comment: Also, most of the benefit of your reply is knowing the why, but since your explanation, I was able to find this code in the library:

     impl<T: Activated> From<Capture<T>> for Capture<dyn Activated> {
          fn from(cap: Capture<T>) -> Capture<dyn Activated> {
              unsafe { mem::transmute(cap) }
          }
     }

Which addresses the problem I'm trying to solve but in an unsafe way.  If there's a better way to handle this at the API level, I can propose a patch.  Thoughts?  Thanks for the great reply!

Comment: @capveg That `transmute` works because there is no vtable actually needed, because the `dyn` type only appears inside `PhantomData`, whereas the rules for `as` aren't looking at whether that's true. (It's still technically unsound because a generic default-repr struct like `Capture` doesn't have a layout guaranteed to be consistent across different type parameters, but that would be easily fixed with `#[repr(C)]`.)

Comment: There is another case that coerces successfully, when `Trait` is an auto trait (that `T` implements, of course).